# How to fix setup.py error when trying to build a Visual Studio Code python solution

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I created a build JSON file and I tried to build my simple python solution but I keep getting this error:

```
can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 2
```

I upgraded `setuptools` but the error is still there.

Comment: What is the build command?  What directory are you in when you run the command?  What files are in that directory?

Comment: I used this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#vscode for my JSON file and I have a very simple flask app with a single python file. @JohnGordon